# Hide attribute added by Manage attribute

Tags: attributes, product-attribute

In project I have added an attribute Status in Dropdown. I want to hide that attribute on adding product page. While Managing Attribute there is no such configuration to hide Attribute. Is there any way to hide attribute on product page ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't want that attribute to be displayed on the Add/Edit Product page from admin, right?

If so, that's not possible by default on Magento.

If you want it to be displayed only on certain products you can try attribute sets. Adding that specific attribute to a specific attribute set will make it visible only to the products that have that attribute set.

But, if you really want to hide it you could try this in a setup script:

```
 $installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', $attribute_code, 'is_visible', '0');
```